# Mostrar notificacion push a cierta hora sin abrir la página

Tags: php, push

Bien, quiero mostrar una notificación push, busqué y me quede con la librería de push.js, y tengo lo básico de esta, muestra la notificación pero solo cuando se accede a la web, y yo quiero que cuando el usuario esté navegando, y tenga las notificaciones activadas le aparezca, con php hice esto, pero me faltaría eso, que no tengan que entrar o actualizar la web para que se vea:

```html
$sql_dbdatos = "SELECT * from ddatos where id=0 ";
$result_dbdatos = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbdatos);
$rows_dbdatos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbdato);

if($rows_dbdatos){
 if(12 <= $hora && $hora <= 14){
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    Push.create("EN VIVO:", {
         body: "' . $rows_dbdatos['dato2'] . '",
         icon: "/icon.png",
         onClick: function() {
             console.log(this);
         }
     });
  
 </script>';
 }
 }
```

Comment: Que hago si no respondió nadie?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió mucho.